# how to echo style element of a class

Tags: php

I am trying to set a class to display none with an echo. 
The name of the class is: **Category-tuts-scripts**

so it should be something like this:

```
echo 'style=".Category-tuts-scripts: display: none"';
```

ofcourse this is not the good syntax but how can I do this?

Comment: Just don't do it! Never use PHP to print or change CSS! Make separated CSS and PHP files!

Comment: ok. I need this in an if statement for distinction between a normal member and a moderator. So how can I load a specific external style in an if statement?

Comment: Then define 2 classes in you CSS file! `.member` and `.moderator`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to do this, but if you really want then place this in the `head` of the document:

`<?php echo '<style type="text/css"> .Category-tuts-scripts { display: none; } </style>'; ?>`

EDIT: In an if statement, if would be as follows:

```
if(!$moderator) {
    echo '<style type="text/css"> .Category-tuts-scripts { display: none; } </style>';
}
```